# How to reload web page inside the web browser control?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, google-chrome-devtools, chromium-embedded

I have developed chrome embedded user control for calling web page in windows app. Now I need to refresh/reload the web page when user click button second time.

I have tried the code below, but it doesn't reload the page.

```
panel.Visible = true;
var settings = new CefSettings
{
    IgnoreCertificateErrors = true,
    CachePath = "<linktoabsolutecachepath>",
    LogFile = "<mylogfile>"
};
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "1");
_chromeBrowser.Refresh();
_chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(_puzzleUrl);

panel.Size = new Size(2000, 1650);
panel.Location = new Point(-450, 364);
panel.Controls.Add(_chromeBrowser);
```

I'm using ChromiumWebBrowser for loading the web page in the panel

Comment: I'm using ChromiumWebBrowser for loading web page

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not necessary to clear all controls and create a new browser every time a reload needed. Instead, you can use the old instance of `ChromiumWebBrowser` and do `_chromeBrowser.Reload()` ([docs](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IBrowser_Reload.htm)). All the rest of the code you posted is also unnecessary for refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

```
_chromeBrowser.Stop(); //Stops loading the current page.
_chromiumWebBrowser.Reload();//Reloads the page being displayed. 
//This method will use data from the browser's cache, if available.
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally I have found better way to solve this issue. Each time on initialising the **ChromiumWebBrowser** object its better to clear the panel which we assigning the chromiumBrowser control in the windows form.

You can clear the panel control :-

**panel.Controls.Clear();**